# netsuite restlet error "message": "ReferenceError: \"Ext\" is not defined. (app-all.js#1)."

Tags: netsuite, restlet-2.0

I deployed a restlet to my server and selected app-all.js. some odd reason when calling it I get that error and that's it.
What am I doing wrong? What should fix it?

Comment: Can you post a sample of the code?  It looks like the error is on the first line so we would need to see what that code looks like.

Comment: this is what I was using. http://www.netsuiterp.com/2018/12/how-to-create-sales-order-with-line.html

Comment: Please post the restlet script.

Answer (score 0):

I found its because I was using suitescript 1.0 and its not supported anymore. I have updated to suitescript 2.0 and not used any dependencies in it and it works correct. Also, not having dependencies will solve the issue.